# Why doesn't any subsequent series after the third series get added on?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to plot 6 series of data but I always get a

> run time error (1004): invalid parameter

on the fourth series. this code worked on my previous project but the data on that project is larger than this current data (see image below). Please help.

[image]

```
Sub CreateChart()

With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=10, Width:=250, Top:=100, Height:=320).Chart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("A2:G5")
    .ApplyLayout Layout:=8
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = "0"
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = "4"
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("A2:A5")
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B2:B5")
    .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Range("A2:A5")
    .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Range("C2:C5")
    .SeriesCollection(3).Values = Range("A2:A5")
    .SeriesCollection(3).XValues = Range("D2:D5")
    .SeriesCollection(4).Values = Range("A2:A5")
    .SeriesCollection(4).XValues = Range("E2:E5")
    .SeriesCollection(5).Name = Range("F1")
    .SeriesCollection(5).Values = Range("A2:A5")
    .SeriesCollection(5).XValues = Range("F2:F5")
    .SeriesCollection(6).Values = Range("A2:A5")
    .SeriesCollection(6).XValues = Range("G2:G5")

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your chart SourceData is not parsed as you expect : the result consists in 3 series only. Thus, calling `SeriesCollection(4)` fails.
Try by using the `PlotBy` argument when setting SourceData to change the way Excel analyze the range :

```vb
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=10, Width:=250, Top:=100, Height:=320).Chart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range("A2:G5"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
        '....
    End With
```